# Google Datastore ancestor query one write per ancestor per second

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When you perform an ancestor query, it is limited to one write per ancestor per second. Does this apply to different entity kinds or the same kind?

For example,
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor

```
class Customer(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Purchase(ndb.Model):
    price = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Order(ndb.Model):
   shipping = ndb.StringProperty()

purchase1 = Purchase(parent=customer_entity.key)
order1 = Order(parent=customer_entity.key)
```

Can you write to both purchase and order at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It applies to the whole entity group, regardless of the entity Kind (actually, Datastore doesn't much care about kinds — only keys and entities).

You can operate separately on your `order` and your `purchase`, but not with the strong consistency of [transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions). If you want strong consistency, then your `customer_entity` will define the scope of that consistency and the reach of the write rate limit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write both purchase and order at the same time. Limitations, when writing entities in the datastore, apply in the case you use [transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions).

For example, in your snippet you may write both entities using `ndb.put_multi()`.

Comment: Thanos is correct regarding using a single put operation. However, the write limit does apply outside transactions. For example, if you had many user requests to create data in the same entity group this would hit the write limit on the entity group. A more appropriate limit rule is "1 write rpc per entity group per second", which is why using `put_multi` allows you to write more than once per second to an entity group.